# Unable to run oc login or reach the URL - minishift/minikube are running

Tags: openshift, minikube, minishift

There's a post similar to this, I tried all the suggestions. Bt that didn't solve my problem.

I am running minishift (minishift v1.34.1+c2ff9cb), openshift-origin-client-tools-v3 on Mac Mojave 10.14.6

Minishift & Minikube are running

```
 oc login https://<ip>:8443 -u developer -p <pwd>
```

When I try oc login I get this error. error: dial tcp :8443: i/o timeout - verify you have provided the correct host and port and that the server is currently running

I have cleaned up, restarted-no luck.

Currently using:

- minishift v1.34.1+c2ff9cb
- minikube version: v1.3.1
- openshift v3

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to resolve.

Delete minikube and reinstalled

```
$ minishift delete --force 
$ rm -rf ~/.minishift/machines/minishift-state.json
minishift profile set minishift
minishift ip
$ minishift start
```

Had to restart my MAC

Started docker, minishift, Minikube

Then launched the url in the browser.

Got certificate error.. Continued with insecure connection

I am able to load the admin console now and create projects